# HAS-A relationship with inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a Class which contains an Object that can only exist within the class. (That is to say that the object would never be used outside of the class.)  As such, I should want the object to have access to the class's protected methods.

Since the Class instantiates the Object, I do not want Object to extend Class, because that would instantiate a Class object which would instantiate the Object, so on and so forth till the end of time.

So, is there a way to allow the Object to have access to the Class's protected methods?

Sorry if this is an easy question to answer, but it is very hard to google this particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is only used within another class, make it an inner class.  See this example:

```
public class DataStructure {

    // Create an array
    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        // fill the array with ascending integer values
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void printEven() {

        // Print out values of even indices of the array
        DataStructureIterator iterator = this.new EvenIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> { } 

    // Inner class implements the DataStructureIterator interface,
    // which extends the Iterator<Integer> interface

    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {

        // Start stepping through the array from the beginning
        private int nextIndex = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {

            // Check if the current element is the last in the array
            return (nextIndex <= SIZE - 1);
        }        

        public Integer next() {

            // Record a value of an even index of the array
            Integer retValue = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfInts[nextIndex]);

            // Get the next even element
            nextIndex += 2;
            return retValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {

        // Fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
        ds.printEven();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just make it an INNER CLASS

This is a useful resource on the subject - http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077411/core-java/inner-classes.html

Answer (score 0):

> As such, I should want the object to have access to the class's
>   protected methods.

Look into creating inner classes. Objects of inner classes can access methods of the enclosing class. Have a look at the [official Java tutorials on nested classes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

**SSCCE:**

```
public class Outer{
    private int value = 99;

    public Outer(){ // Creating an object of Outer class 
        new Inner(); // creates an object of Inner class
    }

    private int getEnclosedValue(){ // Accessor for getting the int value
        return value;
    }

    public class Inner{ 
        public Inner(){ // Constructor for Inner class calls getEnclosedValue()
            System.out.println(getEnclosedValue()); // of the Outer class
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Outer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Other way round is true as well. An enclosing class has access to the members, even private, of its inner classes.

Comment: @JBNizet I never looked into it. Thank you for correcting